# Пагинация главной ВП?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. есть проблемка. есть сайт на ВП, в котором на главной странице выводятся посты. отображается 15 постов. дальше идет пагинация. Но тут то и проблема. она не работает. если нажать на ссылку пагинации, то мы неизбежно перейдем на один пост с сылкой на главную.
вот собственно сайт blago.it-shark.net/
вот собственно цикл вывода постов на главной

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : query_posts($query_string . 'cat=-5,-6');
               while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="ItemDiv">
                           <?php the_post_thumbnail('my-thumb', array('class' => 'resp-img')); ?>
                             <table>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>
                                   <span class="font-16 name bold block uppercase"><?php the_title() ?></span>
                                                            <span class="block uppercase"><?php the_excerpt() ?></span>
                                    </td>
                              </tr>
                             </table>
                             </a>
                           </div>
                       <?php endwhile; ?>
                     <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
                     <?php else: ?>
                    <?php endif;  wp_reset_query();?>
```

ПРошу помочь!

Answer (score 1):

Привет.

Уберите query_posts и добавьте в functions.php что-то вроде этого:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-5,-6' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Также, чтобы не возиться с кодом, Вы можете воспользоваться готовыми плагинами, например, [Ultimate Category Excluder](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-category-excluder/).